# How do I print the selected OptionMenu item every time it is changed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to using classes in python and I'm struggling with this particular task. The code works how I want it to when I run it initially, however when I select either option in the OptionMenu, a big long error shows up, and I cant understand the description of the problem.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def changeChoice(instance, *args):
    if instance.getChoice() == instance.getOptions(0):
        print(instance.getOptions(0))
    else:
        print(instance.getOptions(1))

class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._parent = parent
        self._text = "Text"
        self._choice = StringVar()
        self._choice.set("two")
        self._options = ["one", "two"]
        self._choice.trace("w", changeChoice(self))

    def getParent(self):
        return self._parent

    def getChoice(self):
        return self._choice.get()

    def getOptions(self, listNumber):
        if listNumber == "list":
            return self._options
        else:
            return self._options[listNumber]

    def createMenu(self):
        optionMenu = OptionMenu(ClassA.getParent(self), self._choice, 
*ClassA.getOptions(self, "list"))
        optionMenu.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    instance1 = ClassA(root)
    instance1.createMenu()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: why is `changeChoice()` not a member of ClassA?

Comment: `ClassA.getParent(self)` is just `self._parent` and `ClassA.getOptions(self, "list")` is just `self._options`

Comment: changeChoice() is not a member of ClassA because this happened to be the version of the code where I put it outside classA. I get the same issue regardless of where I put it it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following modifications run without problems

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._parent = parent
        self._text = "Text"
        self._choice = StringVar()
        self._choice.set("two")
        self._options = ["one", "two"]
        self._choice.trace("w", self.changeChoice)

    def changeChoice(self, *args):
        if self.getChoice() == self.getOptions(0):
            print(self.getOptions(0))
        else:
            print(self.getOptions(1))

    def getParent(self):
        return self._parent

    def getChoice(self):
        return self._choice.get()

    def getOptions(self, listNumber):
        if listNumber == "list":
            return self._options
        else:
            return self._options[listNumber]

    def createMenu(self):
        optionMenu = OptionMenu(self._parent, self._choice, *self._options)
        optionMenu.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    instance1 = ClassA(root)
    instance1.createMenu()
    root.mainloop()
```

**Edit**

Looking for a ttk version of OptionMenu I found that `tkinter.OptionMenu` and `ttk.OptionMenu` have a `command` argument.
That gets called when you select an option. The first argument of the callback is the value of the textvariable.

Using it will look like

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._parent = parent
        self._choice = tk.StringVar(value="two")
        self._options = ["one", "two"]

    def changeChoice(self, value, *args):
        print(value)

    def getParent(self):
        return self._parent

    def getChoice(self):
        return self._choice.get()

    def getOptions(self, listNumber=None):
        if listNumber is None:
            return self._options
        return self._options[listNumber]

    def createOptionMenu(self):
        optionMenu = tk.OptionMenu(self._parent, self._choice,
                     *self._options, command=self.changeChoice)
        optionMenu.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    instance1 = ClassA(root)
    instance1.createOptionMenu()
    root.mainloop()
```

The `ttk.OptionMenu`

- uses radiobuttons in the menu that show checkmarks
- strange use of the `default` argument, if you don't specify it the first of your values is the default, and it is removed from the values. The `textvariable` controls the default.
- limits the arguments passed on to the ttk.Menubutton

I have written an alternative `ttk.OptionMenu`:

This class allows you to add a fully constructed menu of your own (you don't need to set the MenuButton as the parent of your Menu) with images and sub menus. If no menu supplied it will construct a menu with `Menu.add_command` based on the list entered as the `values` argument. If you specify a `menu` argument the arguments `command` and `values` are ignored.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ttkOptionMenu(ttk.Menubutton):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        values = kwargs.pop('values', [])
        command = kwargs.pop('command', None)
        textvariable = kwargs.get('textvariable')
        self.menu = kwargs.get('menu')
        if not self.menu:
            self.menu = tk.Menu()
            kwargs['menu'] = self.menu
            for v in values:
                self.menu.add_command(label=v,
                              command=tk._setit(textvariable, v, command))

        self.menu['tearoff'] = 0
        ttk.Menubutton.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

def optionCommand(value, *args):
    print('Changed:', value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    optionVar = tk.StringVar(value='two')
    optMenu = ttkOptionMenu(root, textvariable=optionVar,
                            command=optionCommand, values=['one', 'two'],
                            direction='right')
    optMenu.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Why does `ttk.OptionMenu` destroy the `textvariable` in the `destroy` method? It is not the owner of this variable.